# SLRUM: how to limit CPU number for specific node in one partition when node is in 2 partitions?

Tags: slurm, partition

Actually, I found a very similar question to mine. The only difference is that the number of CPUs of the nodes in my small cluster are different. (The similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66542688/slrum-how-to-limit-cpu-job-count-due-to-avoid-wasting-of-gpu-resource))

For example, the nodes in my cluster are:

- node1, 36 CPUs
- node2, 32 CPUs
- node3, 24 CPUs + 1 GPU
- node4, 16 CPUs + 1 GPU

I have 2 partitions: cpu (all nodes) and gpu (node3,4).

How to leave 4 CPUs in node3 and node4 for gpu partition? In other word, how to configure so that cpu partition includes all CPUs in node1 and node2, 20 CPUs in node3 and 12 CPUs in node4?

(The parameter MaxCPUsPerNode doesn't meet my demand.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the consumable trackable resources plugin (https://slurm.schedmd.com/cons_res.html) instead of the default node allocation plugin, you can set `DefCpuPerGPU` to 4 (see details on setting this variable and enabling `cons_tres` in your `slurm.conf` documentation here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/cons_res.html#using_cons_tres)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this that is a little bit janky but it does get the job done. I have a cluster which has nodes that have different numbers of CPUs. I need a partition that can use all the CPUs from most of the nodes but only a subset of CPUs from another node. As far as I can tell, this specific description is impossible to accomplish with Slurm as it stands.

However, if I create two partitions:

1. **mostnodes**, with `Nodes=n1,n2,n3,n4`
2. **limitednode**, with `Nodes=n5 MaxCPUsPerNode=15`

And then submit jobs with `--partition=mostnodes,limitednode`, the scheduler will schedule the job on whichever partition is first able to run the job. In the words of the [manpage](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html):

> If the job can use more than one partition, specify their names in a
> comma separate list and the one offering earliest initiation will be
> used with no regard given to the partition name ordering (although
> higher priority partitions will be considered first). When the job is
> initiated, the name of the partition used will be placed first in the
> job record partition string.

This isn't a perfect solution but as far as I can tell it is the best solution that is available right now.