# Reserve some CPUs on a node for GPU jobs

Tags: gpu, slurm

I'm setting up a GPU cluster with Slurm. The nodes have a variable number of CPU cores (8-32) and a variable number of GPUs (1-4). The GPU jobs that are going to run generally require very little CPU resource, but there is likely to be a large number of CPU-only jobs running on the cluster as well.

Is there a way that I can "reserve" some CPUs for the GPU jobs? The problem I have at the moment is that if the cluster is backed up with CPU jobs, then any GPU jobs will sit at the end of the queue and the GPUs will be idle. Ideally I'd like to set up separate GPU and CPU partitions, and limit the CPU partition to using e.g. all bar 4 cores on each node, to ensure that there will always be some free for any GPU jobs that come along. However, I've not been able to work out how to allocate part of a node to a partition. I can't use MaxCpusPerNode (as far as I can tell) as the nodes don't all have the same number of CPUs.

I've set up the cluster with a single default partition, SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core and
SelectType=select/cons_tres. The GPU allocations all work fine, but if lots of CPU jobs are scheduled then the GPU jobs get stuck in the queue waiting for CPUs to be free, which is very inefficient.

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

See the suggested solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66542688/slrum-how-to-limit-cpu-job-count-due-to-avoid-wasting-of-gpu-resource). The idea is to register the sam e node to a GPU partition and a CPU partition and limit the number of CPUs usable on the node in each partition.

Comment: I’ve seen that solution, but it doesn’t really work for a heterogeneous cluster where the nodes all have different numbers of cores.

Comment: Agree to that. I have no solution then unfortunately